# subversion 1.6.x(1.7.x) python 2.6+ bindings for Trac

Tags: python, svn, swig, trac

I have Trac 0.12rc1(customized by somebody) it needs python subversion bindings to work with svn repos. But all of my attempts to compile the libraries ended with:

Last command in make:

```
/bin/sh /usr/local/src/subversion-1.6.20/libtool --tag=CC --silent --mode=compile gcc -pthread -fPIC -g -O2   -pthread -DLINUX=2 -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE  -I/usr/local
/src/subversion-1.6.20/subversion -I/usr/local/src/subversion-1.6.20/subversion/include
-I/usr/local/src/subversion-1.6.20/subversion/bindings/swig -I/usr/local/src/subversion-1.6.20/subversion/bindings/swig/include 
-I/usr/local/src/subversion-1.6.20/subversion/bindings/swig/proxy 
-I/usr/local/src/subversion-1.6.20/subversion/bindings/swig/proxy 
-I/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/apr-1  -I/usr/include/python2.6 
-I/usr/local/src/subversion-1.6.20/subversion/bindings/swig/python/libsvn_swig_py
-prefer-pic -c -o subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.lo subversion/bindings
/swig/python/svn_client.c
```

Last part of it's output(all the time looks the same):

```
subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.c:23637: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.c: In function ‘init_client’:
subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.c:23690: error: ‘PyObject’ undeclared (first use in this function)
subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.c:23690: error: ‘m’ undeclared (first use in this function)
subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.c:23690: error: ‘d’ undeclared (first use in this function)
subversion/bindings/swig/python/svn_client.c:23693: error: ‘SwigMethods’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

What I tried:
Python:

- 2.4 (work, but our Trac doesn't work properly with it)
- 2.6 "make swig-py" fails
- 2.7 "make swig-py" fails

Subversion:

- 1.6.17
- 1.6.20
- 1.7.8

SWIG:

- 2.0.9
- 1.3.29

Does anyone had success with building subversion bindings for python2.6+ ?
Is it posible at all?
Is it possible to find any pre-built binaries for RHEL\OEL\CentOS 5.x ?

Comment: *just a guess* -- Look for the python development/header files in your repository.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? How it could help?

Comment: the last part of aa compiler error is the least useful. What's the first bit of the error?

Answer (score 0):

Use this: http://egao1980.blogspot.com/2011/03/installing-trac-and-subversion-with.html

Below copy paste from site:

- Install RPMForge repo `rpm -ihv http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm`
- Good to have
  `yum install bash-completion`
- Black list subversion in `[base]` and `[updates]` repos

`vim /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo`

```
[base]
exclude=subversion
exclude=subversion-devel
...
[updates]
exclude=subversion
exclude=subversion-devel
...
```

- Get 1.6.6 Subversion install script from `www.wandisco.com` and follow instructions to install it.
- Install MySQL.
  `yum install mysql mysql-devel`
- Install Python 2.5, Trac and rebuild mod_python accordig to Installing-python-25-on-centos-5 and Installing-trac-on-centos-5.
- Build Subversion bindings:

**get Sqlite:**

```
wget http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite-autoconf-3070500.tar.gz
tar xzvf sqlite-autoconf-3070500.tar.gz && cd sqlite-autoconf-3070500 && make && make install
```

**get and build SWIG**

```
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/swig/swig/swig-2.0.2/swig-2.0.2.tar.gz
tar xzvf swig-2.0.2.tar.gz && ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python25 --prefix=/usr && make && make install
```

**build Python 2.5 subversion bindings**

```
wget http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-1.6.16.tar.bz2
tar xjvf subversion-1.6.16.tar.bz2 && cd subversion-1.6.16
./configure PYTHON=/usr/bin/python25 --with-sqlite=/usr/local && make && make swig-py && make install-swig-py
echo /usr/local/lib/svn-python > /usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/svn.pth
```

At this point you should have Subversion 1.6.6, Trac 0.12, MySQLDb 1.2.2 and mod_python configured to run with Python 2.5.

Comment: The link http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm is broken.  I tried to use this one: http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/x86_64/repoview/ to find subversion-python packages, but there was none of them.

Comment: Also i tried to look at wandisco binaries. They use python 2.4 and I need at least 2.6. BTW I didn't yet tried 2.5 yet, will do it soon, but not sure if it is backwards compatible with 2.6. Also will try to ask in edgewell maillist. Maybe they have something to fix this.

Comment: @st0ne_c0ld that RPM You can find on ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/epel/5/ppc/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm

Comment: Your link to powerpc, the correct one for x86_64 is http://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm but i didn't mentioned architecture in the question so no problem. Also I reached an IRC channel of Trac users. Someone suggested me to use Debian which is porbably already have everything out of the box. I will try both ways...

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted to the Trac-users maillist and they provided a solution. It was a patch for spec file for rpm building. After patch was applied to the package everything went fine.

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/trac-users/BVVnh9I17Po/discussion